# How to view syslog in docker container (debian:buster)

Tags: c++, docker, syslog

I have a C++ application that writes to syslog.

When I run this application inside a docker container based on the "debian:buster" image, I want to view the output of syslog.

What is the easiest way to view the syslog output?

When I run the application in a container and exec a bash shell in the same container, running journalctl results in:
"No journal entries were found"

Similarly I find nothing in /var/log.

I'm looking for the simplest strategy that doesn't require me to "cout" instead of syslog. I have full control over the Dockerfile used to generate the docker image.